# Is the antipode anti-bracketed?

Tags: quantum-groups, poisson-geometry

In the book [Algebras of Functions on Quantum Groups: Part I](http://bookstore.ams.org/surv-56), Remark 3.1.4, we have the following result.

Let $A$ be a Poisson Hopf algebra. That is, $A$ is both a Hopf algebra and a Poisson algebra and $\Delta: A \to A \otimes A$ is a Poisson algebra homomorphism. Then the antipode $S: A \to A$ is a Poisson algebra anti-automorphism ($S\{a,b\}=-\{S(a), S(b)\}$, $a, b \in A$) and the counit $\epsilon: A \to \mathbb{C}$ is a Poisson algebra homomorphism.

If we do not require the Jacobian condition in a Poisson algebra. Then we obtained a bracked algebra as defined in [R-Matrix Poisson Algebras and Their Deformations](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0351).

An algebra $A$ is bracked if their is a bilinear map $\{,\}: A \otimes A \to A$ such that $\{,\}$ is skew-symmetric and satisfies the Leibniz rule (but not necessarily the Jacobian identity).

Now suppose that $A$ is a bracked Hopf algebra. That is, $A$ is both a Hopf algebra and a bracked algebra and $\Delta: A \to A \otimes A$ is a bracked algebra homomorphism. Do we also have the following result: the antipode is anti-bracked ($S\{a,b\}=-\{S(a), S(b)\}$, $a, b \in A$)? Thank you very much.

Edit: the following is an example of bracketed algebra. We take the following bracket on $\mathbb{C}[GL_3]$ (the indices starts from $0$). 
\begin{align}
& \{ c_{0 0}, c_{0 1} \} =  2  c_{0 0}  c_{0 1}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 0}, c_{0 2} \} =  4  {c_{0 1}}^2  \\ 
& \{ c_{0 0}, c_{1 0} \} =  2  c_{0 0}  c_{1 0}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 0}, c_{1 1} \} =  4  c_{0 1}  c_{1 0}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 0}, c_{1 2} \} =  4  c_{0 1}  c_{1 1} + 2  c_{1 0}  c_{0 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 0}, c_{2 0} \} =  4  {c_{1 0}}^2  \\ 
& \{ c_{0 0}, c_{2 1} \} =  2  c_{0 1}  c_{2 0} + 4  c_{1 0}  c_{1 1}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 0}, c_{2 2} \} =  4  c_{0 1}  c_{2 1} + 4  c_{1 0}  c_{1 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 1}, c_{0 0} \} =  - 2  c_{0 0}  c_{0 1}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 1}, c_{0 2} \} =  2  c_{0 1}  c_{0 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 1}, c_{1 0} \} =  0  \\ 
& \{ c_{0 1}, c_{1 1} \} =  2  c_{0 1}  c_{1 1} - c_{0 0}  c_{1 2} + c_{1 0}  c_{0 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 1}, c_{1 2} \} =  4  c_{0 2}  c_{1 1}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 1}, c_{2 0} \} =  4  c_{1 0}  c_{1 1} - 2  c_{0 0}  c_{2 1}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 1}, c_{2 1} \} =  4  {c_{1 1}}^2 - c_{0 0}  c_{2 2} + c_{0 2}  c_{2 0}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 1}, c_{2 2} \} =  2  c_{0 2}  c_{2 1} + 4  c_{1 1}  c_{1 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 2}, c_{0 0} \} =  - 4  {c_{0 1}}^2  \\ 
& \{ c_{0 2}, c_{0 1} \} =  - 2  c_{0 1}  c_{0 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 2}, c_{1 0} \} =  2  c_{0 0}  c_{1 2} - 4  c_{0 1}  c_{1 1}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 2}, c_{1 1} \} =  0  \\ 
& \{ c_{0 2}, c_{1 2} \} =  2  c_{0 2}  c_{1 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 2}, c_{2 0} \} =  4  c_{1 0}  c_{1 2} - 4  c_{0 1}  c_{2 1}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 2}, c_{2 1} \} =  4  c_{1 1}  c_{1 2} - 2  c_{0 1}  c_{2 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{0 2}, c_{2 2} \} =  4  {c_{1 2}}^2  \\ 
& \{ c_{1 0}, c_{0 0} \} =  - 2  c_{0 0}  c_{1 0}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 0}, c_{0 1} \} =  0  \\ 
& \{ c_{1 0}, c_{0 2} \} =  4  c_{0 1}  c_{1 1} - 2  c_{0 0}  c_{1 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 0}, c_{1 1} \} =  c_{0 1}  c_{2 0} - c_{0 0}  c_{2 1} + 2  c_{1 0}  c_{1 1}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 0}, c_{1 2} \} =  4  {c_{1 1}}^2 - c_{0 0}  c_{2 2} + c_{0 2}  c_{2 0}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 0}, c_{2 0} \} =  2  c_{1 0}  c_{2 0}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 0}, c_{2 1} \} =  4  c_{1 1}  c_{2 0}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 0}, c_{2 2} \} =  4  c_{1 1}  c_{2 1} + 2  c_{2 0}  c_{1 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 1}, c_{0 0} \} =  - 4  c_{0 1}  c_{1 0}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 1}, c_{0 1} \} =  c_{0 0}  c_{1 2} - 2  c_{0 1}  c_{1 1} - c_{1 0}  c_{0 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 1}, c_{0 2} \} =  0  \\ 
& \{ c_{1 1}, c_{1 0} \} =  c_{0 0}  c_{2 1} - c_{0 1}  c_{2 0} - 2  c_{1 0}  c_{1 1}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 1}, c_{1 2} \} =  c_{0 2}  c_{2 1} - c_{0 1}  c_{2 2} + 2  c_{1 1}  c_{1 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 1}, c_{2 0} \} =  0  \\ 
& \{ c_{1 1}, c_{2 1} \} =  2  c_{1 1}  c_{2 1} - c_{1 0}  c_{2 2} + c_{2 0}  c_{1 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 1}, c_{2 2} \} =  4  c_{1 2}  c_{2 1}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 2}, c_{0 0} \} =   - 4  c_{0 1}  c_{1 1} - 2  c_{1 0}  c_{0 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 2}, c_{0 1} \} =  - 4  c_{0 2}  c_{1 1}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 2}, c_{0 2} \} =  - 2  c_{0 2}  c_{1 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 2}, c_{1 0} \} =   - 4  {c_{1 1}}^2 + c_{0 0}  c_{2 2} - c_{0 2}  c_{2 0}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 2}, c_{1 1} \} =  c_{0 1}  c_{2 2} - c_{0 2}  c_{2 1} - 2  c_{1 1}  c_{1 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 2}, c_{2 0} \} =  2  c_{1 0}  c_{2 2} - 4  c_{1 1}  c_{2 1}, \\ 
& \{ c_{1 2}, c_{2 1} \} =  0  \\ 
& \{ c_{1 2}, c_{2 2} \} =  2  c_{1 2}  c_{2 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 0}, c_{0 0} \} =  - 4  {c_{1 0}}^2  \\ 
& \{ c_{2 0}, c_{0 1} \} =  2  c_{0 0}  c_{2 1} - 4  c_{1 0}  c_{1 1}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 0}, c_{0 2} \} =  4  c_{0 1}  c_{2 1} - 4  c_{1 0}  c_{1 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 0}, c_{1 0} \} =  - 2  c_{1 0}  c_{2 0}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 0}, c_{1 1} \} =  0  \\ 
& \{ c_{2 0}, c_{1 2} \} =  4  c_{1 1}  c_{2 1} - 2  c_{1 0}  c_{2 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 0}, c_{2 1} \} =  2  c_{2 0}  c_{2 1}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 0}, c_{2 2} \} =  4  {c_{2 1}}^2  \\ 
& \{ c_{2 1}, c_{0 0} \} =   - 2  c_{0 1}  c_{2 0} - 4  c_{1 0}  c_{1 1}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 1}, c_{0 1} \} =   - 4  {c_{1 1}}^2 + c_{0 0}  c_{2 2} - c_{0 2}  c_{2 0}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 1}, c_{0 2} \} =  2  c_{0 1}  c_{2 2} - 4  c_{1 1}  c_{1 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 1}, c_{1 0} \} =  - 4  c_{1 1}  c_{2 0}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 1}, c_{1 1} \} =  c_{1 0}  c_{2 2} - 2  c_{1 1}  c_{2 1} - c_{2 0}  c_{1 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 1}, c_{1 2} \} =  0  \\ 
& \{ c_{2 1}, c_{2 0} \} =  - 2  c_{2 0}  c_{2 1}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 1}, c_{2 2} \} =  2  c_{2 1}  c_{2 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 2}, c_{0 0} \} =   - 4  c_{0 1}  c_{2 1} - 4  c_{1 0}  c_{1 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 2}, c_{0 1} \} =   - 2  c_{0 2}  c_{2 1} - 4  c_{1 1}  c_{1 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 2}, c_{0 2} \} =  - 4  {c_{1 2}}^2  \\ 
& \{ c_{2 2}, c_{1 0} \} =   - 4  c_{1 1}  c_{2 1} - 2  c_{2 0}  c_{1 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 2}, c_{1 1} \} =  - 4  c_{1 2}  c_{2 1}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 2}, c_{1 2} \} =  - 2  c_{1 2}  c_{2 2}, \\ 
& \{ c_{2 2}, c_{2 0} \} =  - 4  {c_{2 1}}^2  \\ 
& \{ c_{2 2}, c_{2 1} \} =  - 2  c_{2 1}  c_{2 2} 
\end{align}

Comment: What would be a typical bracketed non-Poisson algebra?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, I added an example.

Comment: WOW :D And this is not Poisson?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, this is not Poisson. For example, $Jacobi(c_{00}, c_{01}, c_{12}) = 4\, c_{0,0}\, c_{0,1}\, c_{1,2} - 8\, c_{0,0}\, c_{0,2}\, c_{1,1} + 4\, c_{0,1}\, c_{1,0}\, c_{0,2}$. Here $Jacobi(a,b,c)=\{a, \{b, c\}\} + \{b, \{c, a\}\} + \{c, \{a,b\}\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Suppose $A$ is a bracked Hopf algebra.  Equip $A [\hbar]/\hbar^2$ with the multiplication $a \cdot_\hbar b = ab + \hbar \{a,b\}$.  That this is associative follows from the Leibniz rule --- you do not need Jacobi.  Note that with undeformed $\Delta$, this is Hopf.  (Indeed, it is a bialgebra by inspection. Now suppose $B,\cdot,\Delta$ is a bialgebra, and for $f,g : B \to B$ linear maps, define their *convolution* to be  $f\star g = \cdot \circ (f \otimes g) \circ \Delta$.  Then $\star$ is an associative multiplication on $\hom(B,B)$ with unit $1 \circ \epsilon$, and the antipode, if it exists, is the $\star$-inverse to $\mathrm{id}:B \to B$.  But using that $\cdot_\hbar$ is a deformation of $\cdot$, you can see that if $A$ is Hopf, then so is $A [\hbar]/\hbar^2$.)  But the antipode is always an algebra anti-morphism, and so in particular looking at the order-$\hbar$ part is a bracket anti-morphism.

Comment: thank you very much. What is the antipode of $A[\hbar]/\hbar^2$?

Comment: Is the antipode of $A[\hbar]/\hbar^2$ obtained by extending the antipode of $A$ linearly to $A[\hbar]/\hbar^2$ ($S(a + h b) = S(a) + h S(b)$, $a, b \in A$)?

Comment: what are the unit and counit of $A[\hbar]/\hbar^2$?

Comment: The unit is $1$.  The counit if $\epsilon$.  These do not deform.  (Note that I am thinking of deformed algebra $A[\hbar]/\hbar^2$ as a Hopf algebra over  the dual numbers $\mathbb C[\hbar]/\hbar^2$, so $\epsilon(a+b\hbar) = \epsilon(a) + \epsilon(b)\hbar$.  The point about "it's an open condition" is that you can solve for $S$.

Comment: Let's see.  The rule for the antipode is usually $x_{(1)} \cdot S(x_{(2)}) = x$, where in Sweedler notation $\Delta(x) = x_{(1)} \otimes x_{(2)}$, and I don't write the $\sum$ sign (but it is a nontrivial sum).  So now let $S_\hbar$ denote the sought-after deformed antipode; I want to solve $x_{(1)} \cdot_\hbar S_\hbar(x_{(2)}) = x$, and it suffices to assume $x\in A \subseteq A[\hbar]/\hbar^2$ by $\mathbb C[\hbar]/\hbar^2$-linearity.  By sending $\hbar\to 0$, you see that $S_\hbar(x) = S(x) + S'(x)\hbar$ for $S$ the undeformed antipode.  Then the nontrivial part of the equation is ...

Comment: thank you very much. What is $S'$ in $S_{\hbar}(x) = S(x) + S'(x)\hbar$?

Comment: ... $\{x_{(1)},S(x_{(2)})\} + x_{(1)} S'(x_{(2)}) = 0$.  This is supposed to define the map $S'$.  ($S'$ was just a name for the second component, but it plays the role of $\partial S_\hbar / \partial \hbar$, so in that sense the $'$ is deserved.)

Comment: Here's the fast thing to say.  Recall the convolution $\star$.  Define the deformed convolution $f\star_\hbar g = \cdot_\hbar \circ (f\otimes g) \circ \Delta$ for $f,g$ linear maps, so that $f\star_\hbar g : x \mapsto f(x_{(1)}) g(x_{(2)}) + \hbar \{ f(x_{(1)}),g(x_{(2)})\}$.  Then I can write $\star_\hbar = \star + \hbar \star'$, where $f\star' g = (\{,\}) \circ (f \otimes g) \circ \Delta$.  Now I want to solve $\mathrm{id} \star_\hbar S_\hbar = u \circ \epsilon$, where $u : \mathbb C[\hbar]/\hbar^2 \to A[\hbar]/\hbar^2$ is inclusion of the unit.

Comment: Ok, so then I want to solve $u\circ \epsilon = \mathrm{id} \star S + \hbar \mathrm{id} \star' S + \hbar \mathrm{id} \star S'$, i.e. $\mathrm{id}\star S' = -\mathrm{id} \star' S$.  But $S \star \mathrm{id} = u \circ \epsilon$, and $u \circ \epsilon$ is the identity for $\star$, so $S' = (u\circ \epsilon) \star S' = (S \star \mathrm{id}) \star S' = S \star (\mathrm{id} \star S')$ by associativity of $\star$, and we wanted to solve $\mathrm{id} \star S' = - \mathrm{id} \star' S$.  So we get a formula for $S'$, namely $S' = - S \star (\mathrm{id} \star' S)$.

Comment: In Sweedler notation, $S_\hbar(x) = S(x) - \hbar S(x_{(1)}) \{x_{(2)},S(x_{(3)})\}$.  This should do the trick.

Comment: why $u \circ \epsilon$ is the identity for $\star$?

Comment: Since the antipode is an anti-homomormphism, for $a, b \in A$, we have 
$S_h (a \cdot b) = S_h (b) \cdot S_h (a), \ S(ab) = S(b) S(a).$
Therefore we have $$ S_h(b) \cdot S_h(a) = S_h(a \cdot b) = S_h(ab + h\{a,b\}) =  S_h (ab) + h S_h\{a,b\} \\
 = S(ab) + hS'_h(ab) + h S\{a,b\}, \\
  S_h(b) \cdot S_h(a) = S_h(b)S_h(a) + h \{S_h(b), S_h(a)\} \\
 = (S(b)+hS'_h(b))(S(a) + hS'_h(a)) + h \{S(b) + hS'_h(b), S(a) + hS'_h(a)\} \\
 = S(b)S(a) + hS'(b)S(a) + hS(b)S'(a) + h\{S(b), S(a)\}.$$ ...

Comment: We need the properties $$ S(ab) = S(b) S(a), \\
S'_h(ab) = S(b)S'_h(a) + S'_h(b)S(a), $$ to show that $$ S\{a,b\} = \{S(b), S(a)\} = - \{S(a), S(b)\}. $$

Comment: But in order to have $S′_h(ab)=S(b)S′_h(a)+S′_h(b)S(a)$, we need the property $S_h(ab)=S_h(b)S_h(a)$. We know that $S_h(a\cdot_hb)=S_h(b)\cdot_hS_h(a)$. It seems that we do not have $S_h(ab)=S_h(b)S_h(a)$?

Answer (score 1):

This is also proved in Lemma 2.6 of the paper: [CO-POISSON COALGEBRA AND CO-POISSON HOPF
ALGEBRA STRUCTURES ON $k[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_d]$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.04269v1)
.